# Import to postgreSQL from csv filtering each line

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have the following question (even thorough research couldn't help me):

I want to import data from a (rather large) `CSV/TXT` file to a `postgreSQL DB`, but I want to filter each line (before importing it) based on specific criteria.

**What command/solution can I use?**

*On sidenote:* If I am not reading from file, but a data stream what is the relevant *command/procedure*?

Thank you all in advance and sorry if this has been in some answer/doc that I have missed!

Petros

Comment: What kind of filtering do you need to do? What version of Postgresql are you using? Are you using Linux/Unix, or other?

Comment: Common solution to this is to import into a staging table all the data and to filter off of that table and insert into destination.  SQL is the best tool for filtering and selecting data so why push it down to a language or tool that isn't the best at doing it?  You would be basically mimicking a SQL database.

Comment: 1) Thanx to @benka for his useful edits to my post  
2) @bma - postgreSQL 9.3 with postGIS and pgRouting, Windows 7 64-bit  
3) @JustBob - I know SQL will do the filtering but I don't know the steps to take. Even the term "staging table" is unknown to me. I suppose tho, you mean using `COPY` to insert all the data to a table and then filter that table with a SQL query, which makes perfect sense! In that case, can you upgrade your comment to an answer? However, my sidenote remains unanswered and I could use some heads-up for that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the staging table approach, which is what I use myself:

1. Create a table (could be a temporary table) matching your csv structure
2. Import into that table, doing no filtering
3. Process and import your data into the real tables using SQL to filter and process.

Now, in PostgreSQL, you could also use the file_fdw to give you direct sql access to csv files.  In general the staging table solution will usually be cleaner, but you can do this by essentially letting PostgreSQL treat the file as a table and going through a foreign data wrapper.